# Enable auto - approval option missing in community sub site

Tags: 2013, sub-site, community-site

I want to create a sub site from the community template with unique permission. To achieve this, first I checked using through UI and I found something that is not understandable by me.

First I created a site collection of Community site.
Second I created a sub site of community type with unique permissions.
In the root site there comes an option "Enable auto - approval" under the community settings, but when I went to the sub site and clicked on Community Settings I did not find that option.

[image]
[Image of Community Settings of root site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti4qr.png).

[image]
[Image of Community Settings of sub site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OAjy.png).

Is it not possible to set auto approval in sub site? Or please help me to specify what is the reason behind the option does not appear in the community sub-site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you can't do it for sub community sites

*The Enable auto-approval option is available only for communities that are root site collections and not available for community subsites* [Managing Community Memebership](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-community-membership-HA102925051.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Very old post, but I am doing something similar now. A workaround for Community Sub sites is to add **Everyone** group as Contributor to the site.This will not trigger any approvals and behave like auto-approval.

Please be aware of the consequences and make sure that this site has inheritance broken from the parent.